# doctrine merge: dates without time always updated

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

**UPDATE**: *Question migrated [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603737/doctrine-merge-datetime-field-always-updated): more "general purpose" and understandable.*

---

My entity has a field, mapped to a Doctrine `Date` type.

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="date") */
protected $from;
```

Doctrine has correctly created the Mysql column as a `Date` (without Time), like `2012-12-18`.

I've modified the setter, to create the `DateTime` object:

```
public function setFrom($from){
    $this->from = new \DateTime($from);
}
```

I use `EntityManager->merge()` to update the entity if modified, but it always update the `Date` field because the stored date is always different from the `DateTime` created in the setter (`'2012-12-18' !== "2012-07-08 00:00:00"`).

There's a way to avoid the update, if the date hasn't changed?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're manually calling $em->merge() instead of relying on Doctrine's default behaviour on $em->flush()?

Comment: I do call `flush()`, but before I use `merge` because I crete a new entity regardless it exists in the db, and the `merge` command runs the correct Update or Insert query when "flushed".

Comment: Migrated [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603737/doctrine-merge-datetime-field-always-updated): more "general purpose" and understandable. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the date has changed in your setter to prevent the creation of a new DateTime object:

```
public function setFrom($from){
    if (!$this->from || $form != $this->from->format('your date format')) {
        $this->from = new \DateTime($from);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm creating new entities, so `$this->from` returns null and the date is always updated.

Comment: I crete a new entity regardless it exists in the db, and the `merge` command runs the correct Update or Insert query.
It recognizes changes on fields of int and String type but it always considers the date as changed.