# Doctrine merge: DateTime field always updated

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I create a new Entity with an existing `Id`, and I want to update the related database record.

Doctrine [merge](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities)
has been my best friend: recognizes if there are changes and generates the correct update query.

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setId(1);
$entity->setName('test');
$EntityManager->merge($entity);
$EntityManager->flush();
```

Suppose that the element with the id=1 already exists in the db: if the name is different from 'test', Doctrine generates this query:

```
UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = ? ["test","1"]
```

If I run again the code above, Doctrine recognizes that nothing is changed, and no query is committed.

**But...** when I set a DateTime field, Doctrine consider it as changed and always runs the update query:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setId(1);
$entity->setDate(new \DateTime(2000-01-01));
$EntityManager->merge($entity);
$EntityManager->flush();
//* ALWAYS commits this query:
>> UPDATE table SET date = ? WHERE id = ? ["2000-01-01 00:00:00","1"]
```

Do you know a way to avoid this useless update? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Apparently it's seems to be a bug in Doctrine which is still not resolved(Reference [Github](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/1924))

> That is expected behavior, objects are compared by reference

Comment: Typical programmer approach: _If you can't solve the bug, mark it as a Feature!_ ;)

Comment: I almost downvoted you because I didn't agree with their reason XD

Comment: Java's equals and hash methods are really appropriate here.

Comment: Sometimes I've really had it with Doctrine. Everytime I encounter a bug or an issue, the official response seems to be "fixing this would ruin our precious elegantly crafted code so we'll just do nothing about it and mark it as expected behaviour". I really wonder if these people ever worked on a software project in the real world.

Answer (score 8):

As said by @Raymond, it's the expected behavior.

It's a pity, but if your merge doesn't depend on the `date` property, a workaround could be to set the date after the merge like this:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setId(1);
// Set all fields that the merge is depending on
// ...
$EntityManager->merge($entity);

$entity->setDate(new \DateTime('2000-01-01'));
$EntityManager->flush();
```

**Update**

After tried, the only alternative seems to retrieve the merged object and update it by flushing the EntityManager again.

You can use:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setId(1);
// Set all fields that the merge is depending on
$EntityManager->merge($entity);
$EntityManager->flush();

$entity = $EntityManager->getRepository('Your\Entity')->find(1); // Retrieve the entity
$entity->setDate(new \DateTime('2000-01-01'));
$EntityManager->flush(); // Reflush
```

**Update2**

The cleaner way I found to achieve the update after the merge is re-merge the entity, e.g. :

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setId(1);
// Set all fields that the merge is depending on
$EntityManager->merge($entity); // The real merge that retrieve (without commit) or create
$EntityManager->flush();

$entity->setDate(new \DateTime('2000-01-01'));
$entityManager->merge($entity); // Remerge the object with the changed field
$EntityManager->flush(); // Working re-flush
```

But this doesn't change the main problem and doesn't really make sense because you cannot compare the `DateTime` object by yourself, `$entity->getDate()` return always null before calling `setDate`, even after the first merge.

Doctrine compare the objects by reference (hash) with `===`, also a new instance of `\DateTime` causes the update even if the object date is unchanged.

This is a really problematic issue that could be fixed by using `==` as comparison operator, but doctrine can't make a specific condition for `\DateTime` without breaking their generic object comparison mechanism, that involves to decrease performances of one of the most used feature.

Comment: Sorry I didn't test it properly: it doesen't update the date if changed: it seems to behave the same if you don't set the date at all.

Comment: In case of the entity is new, the date is correctly set ? But not if it's an update ?

Comment: It leaves the date=NULL even if the entity is created new: It seems to ignore all changes made after the merge command (also if I set other fields than the Date). Specifically, if I dump `$entity->getDate()` it prints the date setted. But when flush, the date is committed as NULL.

Comment: See my edit. It's not very clean, but I've made a lot of tries using `EntityManager::clear()`,  `EntityManager::detach($entity)` and it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I'll keep it anyway unaccepted some days (and eventually start a bounty) to see if other solutions come up!

Comment: You're right, I'll look for a cleaner way and come back to see if there is new input in next days :)

Comment: I added a last edit for more precisions and a last approach.

Comment: Hi @T30 , did your regained your bounty ? I saw it disappear and never come back to your rep

Comment: Hi! I tought that the bounty would be given to the most voted answer, so I didn't take care of manually award it.
Now I've re-checked the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and I realize that only half of the points have been assigned...
I'm very sorry... I knew that bounties were non-refundable, but I would have preferred to give you the points for your help.

Comment: Don't worry and thanks for the intention. I just never saw the half of the bounty, maybe I skipped it